Characterization of holomorphic embeddings from $CP^1 \times CP^1$ into $CP^3 \times CP^3$ or $\mathbf{C}^4\times CP^1\times CP^1$.
I am doing research related to twistor and ambitwistor theory, and in my research I am interested in holomorphic embeddings from $CP^1 \times CP^1$ into $CP^3 \times CP^3$ and / or $\mathbf{C}^4\times CP^1\times CP^1$. If either case has been characterized, it would help further my research.  Also, any advice on how to approach this problem would be helpful, although I am not an expert in algebraic geometry or topology so I would be unlikely to find the answer myself with advanced techniques from these fields.  Li and Peterson fully characterized holomorphic immersions from $CP^1 \times CP^1$ into $CP^3$ https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1986-097-03/S0002-9939-1986-0840641-3/S0002-9939-1986-0840641-3.pdf, which are always embeddings, so these results would be a generalization of their results.  I am assuming that the map into $CP^3\times CP^3$ is more likely to have been studied because the space is compact and more amenable to the techniques of algebraic geometry / topology.
I should note that in the end I will be interested in maps into (flat) ambitwistor space, which is the subspace of $(Z,W) \in CP^3\times (CP^3)^V$ satisfying $Z\cdot W=0$, where $(CP^3)^V$ is the dual projective space. Since $(CP^3)^V$ is isomorphic to $CP^3$, it should be easy to find the maps satisfying this condition given the embeddings into $CP^3\times CP^3$, but if this case is better studied then that is all I need.
NOTE : As pointed out in the comments, the map into $\mathbf{C}^4\times CP^1\times CP^1$ must reduce to a constant map into $\mathbf{C}^4$ if there are no singularities (as desired), which reduces to an embedding $CP^1\times CP^1 \rightarrow CP^1\times CP^1$ which is well understood.  I would like to modify this to be the conformal compactification of $\mathbf{C}^4$, which should allow for more non-trivial answers, and will still be relevant to my research (see https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370157383900030 or many other twistor references for the definition of the conformal compactification of $\mathbf{C}^4=M_\mathbf{C}$).  It is useful to know that these maps must pass through the "line at infinity" in order to be non-trivial though.

The only holomorphic map from a compact complex manifold to $\Bbb C^n$ is a constant map. So the only embeddings in $\Bbb C^4\times\Bbb P^1\times\Bbb P^1$ are the trivial ones.

Sorry. I didn't mean to abuse the word trivial. I meant that the $\Bbb C^4$ is irrelevant and you're just talking about maps to $\Bbb P^1\times\Bbb P^1$.  Since you want embeddings, you have to have biholomorphisms, which restricts things quite a bit.

I think this makes sense. Let me just clarify - take spinor coordinates $\lambda$ and $\pi$ for $CP^1 \times CP^1$.  When you say trivial, are you saying that the mapping into $\mathbf{C}^4$ is constant, so that it must take the form $(x, f(\lambda, \pi))$ for some map $f : CP^1 \times CP^1 \rightarrow CP^1 \times CP^1$? We do know that in that case $f$ would take the form $(q(\lambda),p(\pi))$ or $(q(\pi),p(\lambda))$ for q, p projective transformations, making the maps "trivial" in some sense.

Ok yes I agree with you, that is very helpful, thanks!

(The previous comments are in the wrong order because I deleted and edited my comment before seeing the response)

In this case, maybe it would be better to ask about maps into the conformal compactification of $\mathbf{C}^4 \times CP^1 \times CP^1$, I think this might be a more relevant question for my research because if the maps are trivialized in the way you say then that generalization should be reasonable (conformal compactification of $\mathbf{C}^4$ like in this paper https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0370157383900030, or many other references)
